# Update the xml using batch scripting

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I have a file, config.xml, containing:

```
<option name="cfgFileVersion" value="18.0-1" />
<option name="inclLifecyclesFrom" value="B" />
<option name="modifyLifecyclesFrom" value="D" />
<option name="adaptDir" value="C:\work\adaptDir"/>
<option name="sourceDir" value="C:\extra\IMSCL1800500.000"/>
```

I need to replace **in the same configuration file**:

```
<option name="cfgFileVersion" value="18.0-1" />
```

with:

```
<option name="cfgFileVersion" value="18.0.2" />
```

and:

```
<option name="adaptDir" value="C:\work\adaptDir"/>
```

with:

```
<option name="adaptDir" value="New Value 1"/>
```

and:

```
<option name="sourceDir" value="C:\extra\IMSCL1800500.000"/>
```

with:

```
<option name="sourceDir" value="New Value 2"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: Now after you have told us what you want: what is your question? At the moment your post is nothing but a code request, which is clearly off-topic here. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! By the way, if you really have one configuration file, why don't you just edit it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always better to parse XML and other structured markup as a hierarchical object than as flat text to hack and scrape.  Unfortunately, the Batch language doesn't provide objects or methods to handle XML natively this way.

However, you could do it very easily with a PowerShell script.

```js
$fr = @{
    "cfgFileVersion" = "18.0.2"
    "adaptDir" = "New Value 1"
    "sourceDir" = "New Value 2"
}

[xml]$xml = gc config.xml

$fr.Keys | %{
    $xml.SelectSingleNode("//option[@name='$_']").setAttribute("value", $fr[$_])
}

$xml.Save("config.xml")
```

That should be saved with a .ps1 extension. If you *must* have it in the form of a .bat script, you can enclose it in a .bat + PowerShell polyglot by inserting this at the top (before the `$fr =` line) and saving it with a .bat extension:

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
exit /b

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>
```

**Edit:** Here's a full example demonstrating assigning the variable values in Batch and retrieving those values in PowerShell.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "cfgVer=18.0.2"
set "adaptDir=New Value 1"
set "sourceDir=New Value 2"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
exit /b

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

$fr = @{
    "cfgFileVersion" = $env:cfgVer
    "adaptDir" = $env:adaptDir
    "sourceDir" = $env:sourceDir
}

[xml]$xml = gc config.xml

$fr.Keys | %{
    $xml.SelectSingleNode("//option[@name='$_']").setAttribute("value", $fr[$_])
}

$xml.Save("config.xml")
```

Or if you prefer to get rid of the hash table completely and instead scrape a sort of associative array defined in Batch, that can be done as well.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "config[cfgFileVersion]=18.0.2"
set "config[adaptDir]=New Value 1"
set "config[sourceDir]=New Value 2"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
exit /b

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

[xml]$xml = gc config.xml

gci env: | ?{ $_.Name -match "^config\[(.+)\]$" } | %{
    $xml.SelectSingleNode("//option[@name='$($matches[1])']").value = $_.Value
}

$xml.Save("config.xml")
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your reply. But the thing is , i need it in the .bat scripts only . not in power shell. Because the    New Value 1 New Value 2 are the values stored in a variable %a% , %b%.